# Ошибок нет ,но переход на другую страницу не осуществляется

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.nurasyl;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;
    public void addListenerOnButton () {
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(".MainActivity2");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );}

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


}
```

**MainActivity2.java**

```
package com.example.nurasyl;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/sur"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="371dp"
        android:layout_height="198dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="41dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="364dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:text="@string/main_text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="305dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
        android:text="@string/button"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="179dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="223dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:background="@color/white"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/start"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="23dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="53dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/buttonprivet"

        />.

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button1"


        />.

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button2"

        />.

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="277dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:text="@string/button3"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">


        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/privet"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nurasyl">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Nurasyl">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".MainActivity2" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
   
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]